# How do I create a cascading parameter of dates in SQL Server Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am creating a report in which the user selects the start date (month and year) and end date (month and year) from a drop-down list.

The end date drop-down list should only include dates which are after the start date, so I figure that this should be a cascading parameter.

How could I do this?

Comment: Depends, do you want to use the date picker or not? If not, how much are you limiting the "after" to? 7 days, 14 days? 365 days? If it's a lot (like 265) this is going to be a problem. If you want the date picker, then you can't do this; limiting the valid values on a date input on SSRS turns it into a free type or drop-down. My honest answer, let them pick anything; they won't get any data if they're being "silly" and picking a start date after the end date. They'll soon realise, or if they call you, you can ask  them (in a non-patronising way) to explain when the end is before the start. :)

Comment: I avoid fetching date values from the server and populating report parameters as this can adversely impact performance. The alternative solution is to check the incoming data parameters to see if the start date is before the end date. If not, throw an error. Is this possible on your end?

Comment: @Larnu I have thought about doing that. I would have preferred having a system that prevents users from picking silly dates in the first place, but I'm not a developer, so I wasn't even sure if that was possible in Report Builder. I suppose I will take J Weezy's suggestion  and just throw an error if nonsensical dates are chosen...

Comment: @Larnu The only dates that are relevant for this report are by month. In other words, the exact day of the month is irrelevant and does not have to be included. Do you know if there is a way to add a drop-down box (such as those used for other, non-date parameters) with month + year that adds new months as the year progresses? For example, a month from today, a "July 2018" option would be added.

Comment: You could do something like that,sure. I'd still suggest limiting the results, however, only needing the month and year massively limits it already. I'm afraid I won't get a chance till tomorrow to show how to do this now though.